# Немогу понять в чем проблема, можете помочь? Не обновляються данные пользователя

Tags: php, mysql

```
include "connectdb.php";
    session_start();
          if ($_SESSION['auth'] == false) 
          {
           echo "You don't login!!!";
          }
          if ($_SESSION['auth'] == true)
          {
              if(isset($_POST['submit']))
              {
                session_start();
                $login = $_POST['login'];
                $password = $_POST['pass'];
                $about = $_POST['about'];

                $id = $_SESSION['id'];
                $login = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $login);
                $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $password);
                $about = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $about);
                $password=md5($password);

                $query = "UPDATE users SET login='$login', password='$password', about='$about' WHERE id='$id'";
                $result = mysqli_query($db,$query);
                if ($result)
                {
                    echo "Profile edited";
                }
              }
          }
```

Comment: ошибка какая? вы включили вывод ошибок?

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте убрать второй `session_start()` и поменять проверку `$_SESSION` на проверку не через сравнение, а через `if(isset($_SESSION['auth']))`

Без более подробного объяснения сложно, запись не проходит в базу с какой то ошибкой, или просто так..

Возможно стоит переписать вашу `$query` в такой вид:

```
$query = "UPDATE `users` SET login='".$login."', password='".$password."', about='".$about."'WHERE id= '".$id."'";
```

Comment: На счет сессии, в входе в профиль создаеться сессия auth которая равна true (если в входе в профиль ошибка, то значение сессии равна false). Так, что на счет сессий ошибка

Comment: И кстати, не работает...

Comment: Я нашел ошибку, просто синтаксис запроса чуть другой

Comment: и какой же? напиши, чтоб люди которые могут с таким столкнутся, имели решение

Comment: $sql  = 'UPDATE `users` SET `login`="'.$login.'", `password`="'.$password.'", `about`="'.$about.'", `Country`="'.$country.'", `City`="'.$city.'", `religion`="'.$religion.'", `job`="'.$job.'", `name`="'.$dsew.'",   WHERE `id` = "'.$id.'"';